# Django REST Framework + Django REST Swagger + ImageField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-swagger

I created a simple Model with an ImageField and I wanna make an api view with django-rest-framework + django-rest-swagger, that is documented and is able to upload the file.

Here is what I got:

**`models.py`**

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):

    source = models.ImageField(upload_to=u'/photos')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"photo {0}".format(self.source.url)
```

**`serializer.py`**

```
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            'id',
            'source',
            'created_at',
        ]
```

**`views.py`**

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializer import MyModelSerializer

class MyModelView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser, )

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Create a MyModel
            ---
            parameters:
                - name: source
                  description: file
                  required: True
                  type: file
            responseMessages:
                - code: 201
                  message: Created
        """
        return super(MyModelView, self).post(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

**`urls.py`**

```
from weddings.api.views import MyModelView

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^/api/mymodel/$', MyModelView.as_view()),
)
```

For me this should be pretty simple. However, I can't make the upload work. I always get this error response:
[image]

I've read this part of the documentation from [django-rest-framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#fileuploadparser):

`If the view used with FileUploadParser is called with a filename URL keyword argument, then that argument will be used as the filename. If it is called without a filename URL keyword argument, then the client must set the filename in the Content-Disposition HTTP header. For example Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=upload.jpg.`

However the Header is being passed by django-rest-swagger in the Request Payload property (from chrome console).

If any more info is necessary, please let me know.

I'm using `Django==1.8.8`, `djangorestframework==3.3.2` and `django-rest-swagger==0.3.4`.

Comment: Do you have Pillow installed? I believe django rest needs it to process image files
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow

Comment: Thank You Charles .. but yes, I do have Pillow installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the final solution I came up with:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.parsers import FormParser, MultiPartParser
from .serializer import MyModelSerializer

class MyModelView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Create a MyModel
            ---
            parameters:
                - name: source
                  description: file
                  required: True
                  type: file
            responseMessages:
                - code: 201
                  message: Created
        """
        return super(MyModelView, self).post(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

All I had to do was change the parsers from `FileUploadParser` to `(FormParser, MultiPartParser)`

Comment: What do you need to do to get DRF or DRF-Swagger to pick up that yml? I set a docstring like that, but it just renders as Markdown under "Implementation Notes"

Comment: I don't have much in my settings. I'ts pretty much the basic from the django-rest-swagger docs. However, I'm using version `0.3.7` of django-rest-swagger.

Answer (score 8):

I got this working by making a couple of changes to your code.

First, in `models.py`, change `ImageField` name to `file` and use relative path to upload folder. When you upload file as binary stream, it's available in `request.data` dictionary under file key (`request.data.get('file')`), so the cleanest option is to map it to the model field with the same name.

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):

    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=u'photos')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"photo {0}".format(self.file.url)
```

In `serializer.py`, rename source field to file:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'file', 'created_at')
```

In views.py, don't call super, but call create():

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser

from .serializer import MyModelSerializer


class MyModelView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
            Create a MyModel
            ---
            parameters:
                - name: file
                  description: file
                  required: True
                  type: file
            responseMessages:
                - code: 201
                  message: Created
        """
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I've used Postman Chrome extension to test this. I've uploaded images as binaries and I've manually set two headers:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=upload.jpg
Content-Type: */*
```

Comment: I tried the changes you suggested, but now I'm experiencing a different error:
`Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image`

Answer (score 3):

It has been my experience that the `FileUploadParser` works with this format of a request:

```
    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" \
                 -F "file=@{filename};type=image/jpg" \
                 https://endpoint.com/upload-uri/
```

The `request.data['file']` in your view will have the file.

Maybe if you try a `Content-Type:multipart/form-data` header, you will have luck.

Comment: Thank you zemekeneng, but I still get and error:
`{"file":["The submitted file is empty."]}`. That did not worked.

Comment: Maybe try calling it with `curl` and make sure that the file name is inside the `{}` so it looks like `file=@{path/to/file}`, if this works, then the issue might be client-side. Good luck!